# pulling photo from url and placing on screen

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

What's the proper way to add a photo from a url to my main.xml and having that placed on my activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of simple examples of this online, but the easiest way is probably to just use [droid-fu](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu)'s [WebImageView](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/), which comes with lots of other goodies, too. If you do roll your own, the most important part is "don't do the downloading in the UI thread," which will make your app unresponsive.